# How to get a dollar sign in Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have been lookinig through this : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

However I still have difficulties to write the right command to get all the expression folllowing this pattern :

```
 <$FB $TWTR are getting plummetted>
```

(<> just signal the beginning of the sentence-tweet actually as I am parsing twitter). I want to extract FB TWTR.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Comment: What are the exact requirements? "*command to get all the expression folllowing this pattern*" You want to capture the whole string or just the message inside?

Comment: If you want a one-regex solution, [have a look at this regex](https://regex101.com/r/kK9hE5/1). It will work in Java (just double-escape backslashes). However, I'd rather get the `<...>` substring with `<[^>]*?>` and then split by space and check each element if it starts with `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a 2-step approach: we extract `<...>` groups with a regex and then split the chunks into words and see if they start with `$`.

```
String s = "<$FB $TWTR are getting plummetted>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<([^>]+)>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    String[] chks = matcher.group(1).split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i<chks.length; i++)
    {
        if (chks[i].startsWith("$"))
            System.out.println(chks[i].substring(1));
    }
}
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/paYpYq)

And here is a 1-regex approach ([see demo](http://ideone.com/zloZBX)), use only if you feel confident with regex:

```
String s = "<$FB $TWTR are getting plummetted>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:<|(?!^)\\G)[^>]*?\\$([A-Z]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

The regex used here is [`(?:<|(?!^)\G)[^>]*?\$([A-Z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/kK9hE5/1).

It matches:

- `(?:<|(?!^)\G)` - A literal `<` and then at the end of each successful match
- `[^>]*?` - 0 or more characters other than `>` (as few as possible)
- `\$` - literal `$`
- `([A-Z]+)` - match and capture uppercase letters (replace with what best suits your purpose, perhaps `\\w`).

Comment: Thanks very much for the very detailed explanation. Really appreciate that mate.

Comment: You are welcome. If you find my answer helpful, please also consider upvoting.